# Efficiency of Ramp

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A 50.0 kg block slides across a horizontal floor. The block is traveling at 8.0 m/s when it begins to slide up an inclined ramp. The block stops after rising 2.0 m as it slides 9.0 m along the ramp. What is the efficiency of the ramp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is about efficiency, we can reasonably assume the ramp is not frictionless. If it had been, it would be 100% efficient and there would be no question. For a frictionless ramp, all the kinetic energy would have been converted to potential energy, and the block would have risen to a height $h=\frac{v^2}{2g}=3.2~\rm{m}$. The fact that it only rose to 2.0 m tells us part of the energy was converted to heat (friction).

The efficiency of the ramp tells us what fraction of the input energy (kinetic energy) does useful work (lifting). If you have initial kinetic energy $E=\frac12 m v^2$ then on a frictionless ramp you should be able to reach a height $h=\frac{v^2}{2g}$. For an initial velocity of 8.0 m/s, that implies a height of 3.26 m.

Lifting to 2.0 m when you input enough energy to get to 3.26 m means the efficiency is $\frac{2.0}{3.26}$ = 61%

The rest of the kinetic energy is converted to heat. We can figure out the total heat by looking at the difference in potential energy between a block at a height of 3.26 m and a block at 2.0 m: the energy difference is $m g \Delta h = 50~\rm{kg} \cdot 9.81~\rm{m/s^2} \cdot 1.26~\rm{m} = 618~\rm{J}$. Alternatively you could calculate the difference between the initial kinetic energy and the final potential energy - the answer would be the same.

Note that the distance along the ramp (9.0 m) is irrelevant unless you need to calculate the coefficient of friction.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256092/efficiency-and-frictional-heat-of-ramp

$\frac{2.0}{3.26}???????????????

plz refrain from words like "obvious" as i am asking a for help. If all were obvious then this site would not exist

Comment: my teacher final told me the answer and it was on nothing in the readings or anything we covered. We also never covered h=v^2/2g like i said this is basic physic grade 11..... your answer is right. but i could have never solved it that way with the info given to me.... efficiency= (Wo/Wi)100 = (mgh/.5mv^2)100 =((50*9.8*2)/(.5*50*8^2))100 = 61%

Comment: Did you not learn about kinetic energy and potential energy? The expression I used just rearranged $mgh= \frac12 m v^2$; kinetic energy is converted to potential energy.

Comment: E1 = mgh+.5mv^2 = 0 +(.5)(50kg)(8)^2 = 1600J
E2 = mgh+.5mv^2 = (50)(9.8)(2) + 0 = 980J
 
E1 - E2 = E(f)

1600J-980 = 620 J of frictional heat

(E2/E1)x100= 61%

thank you I've looked into your example and it has helped me understand everything in a new light. I am still learning and have ways to go.

Comment: Yes. I think you have understood! Well done and keep going.